# prove that $g(x) = \sqrt{x}, x\in [0, \infty]$ is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, derivatives, radicals

How to prove that $g(x) = \sqrt{x}, x\in [0, \infty]$ is differentiable?

Is my proof correct?

Let $x_0 \in [0, \infty]$.

$
\begin{align}
\lim_{h \downarrow 0} \frac{g(x_0 + h) - g(x_0)}{h} &= \lim_{h \downarrow 0} \frac{\sqrt{x_0 + h} - \sqrt{x_0}}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h \downarrow 0} \frac{ \sqrt{x_0} - \sqrt{x_0} }{h} \\
&= 0 \\
&= \lim_{h \uparrow 0} \frac{ \sqrt {x_0 + h} - \sqrt{x_0}}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h \uparrow 0} \frac{g(x_0 + h) - g(x_0)}{h} \\
\end{align}$

Comment: can you assume continuity?

Comment: correct me if I am wrong: if a function is differentiable on some domain then it implies that it is continous on that domain

Comment: You have just shown that $g'(x)=0\ \forall x \in [0,\infty]$. That's hideously wrong. More, your function has an undefined derivative at $x=0$

Comment: Your proof is not correct. How do you justify the second equality?

Comment: @jublikon yes, but you need to do more work, $\sqrt{x_0+h}\to \sqrt{x_0}$ if you know continuity. Another note is that it is goes to $\sqrt {x_0}$ so $\sqrt{x_0+h}-\sqrt{x_0}=L\to0$ and you can't say $L/h=0$

Comment: In your second displayed line, you substitute $h=0$ in the numerator but not the denominator.  This is a big no-no.  Either all the $h$'s go to zero or none.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but you need $x>0$ and to continue:
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0^+}\frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow0^+}\frac{(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x})(\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x})}{h(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x})}=$$
$$=\lim_{h\rightarrow0^+}\frac{x+h-x}{h(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x})}=\lim_{h\rightarrow0^+}\frac{h}{h(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x})}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}.$$

Comment: Can you explain your steps a bit more detailed please? That would be very great. I have some trouble to understand your equation

Comment: @jublikon I added something. See now. I used $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$.

Comment: @jublikon multiply and divide by $\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt x$

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is wrong.

Having a glance to the result, we see you ve just proved that g(x) is a constant
(since its derivative is 0 on a connected domain), and that's obviously not true (your mistake is that if the numerator goes to zero, that doesn't mean the wholr fraction goes to zero. In fact, if a function is derivable, the fraction has to present an undecision form: $\frac{0}{0}$ (which is not necessarily $0$). That's why a differentiable function is continuous: because $\lim_{h \to 0} f(x+h)-f(x)=0$

Doing in a correct way your calculation, we get that for $x>0$:

$\begin{equation}g'(x)=\lim_{h \to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{h}=\lim_{h \to \infty}\frac{h}{h(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{h})}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\end{equation}$

Where the second equality is justified multiplying both numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be *any* continuous function on some interval $(a,b)$. Then, for $x_0\in(a,b)$,
$$
\lim_{h\to0}f(x_0+h)=f(x_0)
$$
That's continuity, isn't it? Well some take this as the definition, others as a consequence, but it doesn't really matter.

Now, if your argument for the square root were sound, it would be also for our arbitrary $f$:
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}
\overset{\color{red}{!!!}}=
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x_0)-f(x_0)}{h}=0
$$
(the three red exclamation marks point to the wrong step) so the derivative of *any* continuous function would be everywhere zero. This would make derivatives quite boring stuff.

You ***aren't*** allowed to replace ***only part*** of a function with its limit, when computing limits. Also the following one is incorrect:
$$
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}\overset{\color{red}{!!!}}=
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{1-1}{x-1}=0
$$
According to this line of reasoning, every limit in the “indeterminate form” $0/0$ would be $0$, which it generally isn't: the right answer for the above limit is $2$:
$$
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{x-1}
=\lim_{x\to1}(x+1)=2
$$